# Remove "Open with GIMP" from context menu?

Tags: windows-vista, uninstall, context-menu, gimp

I recently uninstalled GIMP on my Vista laptop, but there is still an `Open with GIMP` option on the context menu for most image file types, like JPEG and PNG. Clicking this option results in an error dialog.

Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Crap Cleaner (CCleaner) to deal with it or edit the registry for HKLM_Classes and look for the .JPG, .PNG, .BMP, there's a key in there for Open, I have given jpegfile as an example, do the same for .PNG and so on... **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jpegfile\shell\Open with GIMP** (Backup your registry before doing this..)

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: One can also search "Open with GIMP" and delete, and then press F3 to locate the next one.

Answer (score 8):

For editing context menus, nirsoft's [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) is both fantastic and free - highly recommended.

Locate and **highlight** the Gimp shell extension and press **F7** (or right click on it and select **Disable Selected Items**).

Comment: +1 was going to post that before I saw you already did!

Comment: "Open with foo" items are rarely shell extensions - it's a lot easier for a programmer to simply add another command to a specified file t ype. (See tommieb75's answer.)

Comment: The program looks useful, but as grawity said, there isn't an "Open with GIMP" shell extension.

Comment: @Ben Use [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) instead.

Answer (score -2):

Open regedit.

back up registry first (to be safe) by selecting export and ticking ALL.

go to EDIT then use Find to look for all instances with "Open with GIMP"

once found, delete it then use Find next (F3) for the next one.